# Como se diz "It is worth mentioning that " em Portuguese?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, frases

Se eu não me engano "Vale a pena" significa "It is worth mentioning that".

Queria saber se existe um frase mais formal para dizer "It is worth mentioning that" em Portuguese?

Comment: “É notável”, “Devemos/Deve-se mencionar”, “Vale dizer”.

Comment: _Importa referir/mencionar/assinalar que_...

Comment: @Artefacto Nunca escutei esse. Imagino que seja de uso comum a Portugal, não?

Comment: @William - "vale dizer" tem outro significado; é sinônimo de "é o mesmo que dizer".

Comment: @LuísHenrique Mais um meio termo. Os exemplos dados no resultado para a expressão no ciberdúvidas mostra como ela precede uma conclusão que se deve salientar. Frases inciadas com "Vale dizer que..." também são interpretadas como tal.

Comment: @William aquelas expressões do Artefacto não são de uso muito comum em Portugal porque têm um registo mais formal e trabalhado, mas vão sendo usadas e são imediatamente reconhecidas sem estranheza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It's worth mentioning that..."

Sugestões de um falante de pt-Br.

Vejamos as frases em Inglês que obtive no Google Books:

> - It's worth mentioning that some cars don't take gas conversions.
>     **"Vale a pena mencionar que..."**
> - The last point is worth mentioning since the interpretation of the extension 
>     of dignity very much dominated the ... 
>     **"O último ítem vale a pena ser mencionado, visto que..."**
> - However, it is worth mentioning that the Internet is by and large an unregulated medium ...
>     **"No entanto, vale a pena mencionar que a Internet é..."**

Nos exemplos acima, "vale a pena mencionar que..." soa bem natural. Em outros contextos, "vale a pena ressaltar que", "devo mencionar que", "É importante frisar/ressaltar/mencionar que...", "nunca é demais mencionar que...", "notem bem que", podem ser mais apropriados.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas sugestões mais formais:

> - É importante notar que...;
> - É válido mencionar que...;
> - Vale mencionar que...

Answer (score 0):

Estas são as minhas sugestões:

- Vale a pena mencionar que
- Vale a pena citar
- Vale a pena dizer que